# Change Flyway resources location for scala unit test

Tags: scala, maven, unit-testing, slick, flyway

I am trying to write the scala test cases for a `maven`, which involves Flyway 
I have my SQL scripts located in the `/src/main/resources/db/migration` while for the test cases I need to have my test scripts location to be `/src/test/resources/db/migration/test.sql` 
I know we can specify the change of resource by configuring the `location` property of flyway 
Is it possible to configure two different resource location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you are trying to specify scripts location via build configuration. Why don't you just call `Flyway.setLocations ("some/path/test.sql")` explicitly from the code of test?

Comment: Tried setting `Flyway.setLocations (...)` but it says `Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location`

Comment: You got me wrong. `setLocations` accepts a vararg of paths. I edited my answer.

Comment: I meant the same , the problem was it was looking for the files at `classpath` instead of `filesystem`. 
tried with `Flyway.setLocations ("filesystem:some/path/")` and it worked like charm